# use LINQ to remove items from a list based on a date

Tags: c#, list, linq

In C# I have a list `locationsList` which contains fields `location` and `date`,
`location` can appear multiple times with different dates.

If `location` does appear multiple times I want to only keep the one with the latest date.
Is there any way to do this using LINQ rather than iterate through the list and compare the dates of each multiple-occurring location?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your current code.

Comment: As dymanoid mentioned, we can't really answer this if there's no code sample. Look into **grouping** the data based on the fields that are important to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the field `location` is a string, and you can rebuild your Location object:

```
class Location {
    public string location { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

var distincts = locationsList 
         .GroupBy(location => location.location)
         .Select(grp => new Location {
             location = grp.Key, 
             date = grp.Max(loc => loc.date)
         });
```

If rebuilding your object is not an option, you can use the [MaxBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) extension method by [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.github.io/):

```
var distincts = locationsList 
         .GroupBy(location => location.location)
         .Select(grp => grp.MaxBy(loc => loc.date))
```

For simplification, here is a non generic version of the MaxBy method, applied to your case:

```
Location MaxByDate(List<Location> locations){
    Location maxLocation = null;
    var maxDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach(var location in locations) {
        if (location.date > maxDate)
        {
            maxLocation = location;
            maxDate = location.date;
        }
    }
    return maxLocation ;
}
```

**Edit**

Another alternative proposed by [Flater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/952296/flater), slightly worst in performance due to the fact that you must loop twice in each group, one for retrieving the Max, the second loop for finding the match. But very readable and maintainable.

```
var distincts = locationsList 
     .GroupBy(location => location.location)
     .Select(grp => {
         var maxDate = grp.Max(location => location.date);
         return grp.First(location => location.date == maxDate);
     })
```

Comment: It can be done without MoreLINQ too: `Select(group => group.First(x => x.Date == group.Max(y => y.Date))`. A bit more verbose, but possible. (note that I used `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault` because null should logically never be encountered after a `GroupBy`)

Comment: @Flater, that will compute `Max` on the group for every item in the original source. This will have terrible performance. If you want to go that route, compute the max before calling `First`.